# I can't seem to find why the states on my React.js project are not updating

Tags: reactjs

Here is the constructor of my project.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstname: "kaus",
            lastname: "",
            telnum: "",
            email: "",
            agree: false,
            contactType: "Tel.",
            message: "",
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState = ({
            [name]: value
        });
        console.log(name+": "+value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        alert("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

and inside the return(), this is from where I am calling the handleInputChange() function

```
    <FormGroup row>
        <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
        <Col md={10}>
            <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </Col>
    </FormGroup>
```

I have tried console.log() inside handleInputChange() function.

```
console.log(name+": "+value);
```

It works just fine. But the states are not updating.

[Here is the screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6mtq.png)

Comment: how could you know that state is not updated? did you console.log in `handleInputChange()` too?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the post I have console.log in handlInputChange(). It is working as seen in the image provided.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved.
I was using

```
    this.setState = ({
        [name]: value
    });
```

instead of

```
    this.setState ({
        [name]: value
    });
```